# NAA review getting worse

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, disputed-review-audits

As you can see in the following [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZlEA.png):[image]

The posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55091573/3654837) doesn't attempt to answer or might as well belong to another question. Yet the flag got declined.

Comment: The CSS they've included seems to be an attempt to answer their question: "Show dropdown menu on hover css". What makes you think it's not an attempt?

Comment: The other answer does attempt with related code. But the linked answer doesn't use the related code at all. With 0 explanation.

Comment: @Mukyuu People, with varying level of reputation, have been inventing code that is totally not in questions to answer, for years. Expressing a concept, is not necessarily dependent on reusing the code in a question. There is no requirement to use the code in a question, if an answerer feel they can do better without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The posted answer doesn't attempt to answer

Yes, it is an answer; how is it not? The question is:

> Can't style menu for sub menu items to dropdown on hover.

The answer is a navbar, with HTML markup with CSS style for the on hover selector. That is most definitely, without doubt, an attempt to answer.

Whether that is an accurate, or good answer, on the other hand... If you feel the accuracy or usefulness of such a post is very low, because you are a domain expert or because as a learner the post did not teach you anything, then by all means, downvote it.

But for the flag, as is being said: **not an answer is not a flag that is supposed to indicate a technical inaccuracy**.